# How can I add Uber onto the contact us / location page of a website

Tags: uber-api

I am wanting to add the ability for people to order an Uber to our location from our website so when mobile users are looking for us they can get an Uber straight to us with the location ore populated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via deeplinks. A guide & generator of Uber deeplinks can be found here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction